# Angular filter to format temperature

Tags: javascript, converting, angular.js, formatting, jasmine

This a basic filter I created with Angular that does temperature conversion. I'd like to get thoughts on how to improve this code from both an Angular and general JS perspective.

The filter should take 2 arguments:

- `scale`: The temperature scale to convert to
- `label`: Whether to append a degree symbol to the number

**In the view:**

```
// should output: 99
{{ 37 | formatTemperature: 'F' }}

// should output: 99°
{{ 37 | formatTemperature: 'F':true }}

// should output: 37
{{ 98.6 | formatTemperature: 'C' }}
```

**The filter:**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('example')
    .filter('formatTemperature', [
      function() {
        return function(input, scale, label) {
          var value = parseInt(input, 10),
              convertedValue;

          if (isNaN(value)) throw new Error('Input is not a number');

          if (scale === 'F') {
            convertedValue = Math.round(value * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32);
          } else if (scale === 'C') {
            convertedValue = Math.round((value - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0);
          } else {
            throw new Error('Not a valid scale');
          }

          return label ? convertedValue += '\u00B0' : convertedValue;
        };
      }
    ]);
})();
```

**Testing the filter:**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  describe('formatTemperature test', function() {
    beforeEach(module('example'));

    var filter;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$filter_) {
      filter = _$filter_('formatTemperature');
    }));

    it('should convert temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit', function() {
      expect(filter(37, 'F')).toEqual(99);
    });

    it('should convert temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius', function() {
      expect(filter(98.6, 'C')).toEqual(37);
    });

    it('should append a % to the converted value', function() {
      expect(filter(37, 'F', true)).toEqual('99\u00B0');
    });

    it('should throw an error if the scale is invalid', function() {
      expect(function() {
        filter(37, 'G');
      }).toThrow(new Error('Not a valid scale'));
    });

    it('should throw an error if value is not a number', function() {
      expect(function() {
        filter('test', 'F');
      }).toThrow(new Error('Input is not a number'));
    });
  });

})();
```

Comment: So what happens if I have a temperature given in Kelvin?

Comment: You might have a look at https://github.com/gentooboontoo/js-quantities ;)

Answer (score 2):

On the principal that functions should do one thing and do it well, consider breaking out some pieces of your filter into smaller functions for readability.

**Filter**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('example')
        .filter('formatTemperature', formatTemperatureFilter);

    var degreesSymbol = '\u00B0';

    function convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(value) {
        return Math.round(value * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32);
    }

    function convertFahrenheitToCelsius(value) {
        return Math.round((value - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0);
    }

    function addDegreesSymbol(value) {
        return value += degreesSymbol;
    }

    function formatTemperatureFilter() {
        return function (input, scale, label) {
            var value = parseInt(input, 10),
                convertedValue;

            if (isNaN(value)) throw new Error('Input is not a number');

            if (scale === 'F') {
                convertedValue = convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(value);
            } else if (scale === 'C') {
                convertedValue = convertFahrenheitToCelsius(value);
            } else {
                throw new Error('Not a valid scale');
            }

            return label ? addDegreesSymbol(convertedValue) : convertedValue;
        };
    }

})();
```

Make sure that your tests are testing one thing!

This will fail if you changed your conversion functions. Maybe you want to add 1 decimal place in the future.

```
it('should append a % to the converted value', function() {
      expect(filter(37, 'F', true)).toEqual('99\u00B0');
});
```

Change to a matcher that looks for the degrees symbol

```
it('should append a degrees symbol to the converted value', function() {
     expect(filter(37, 'F', true)).toContain('\u00B0');
});
```

Lastly, the only acceptable values for the scale are `F` and `C`, should this be case sensitive?